# Obtener datos de fragmentos y mostrarlos en otro fragmento de la misma actividad

Tags: android, android-studio

Quisiera saber si se pueden obtener los datos que se introducen en un editext de un fragment y poder mostrarlos en otro editext de otro fragmento sin la necesidad de un botón, con blunde.

los fragmentos que utilizo son de desplazamiento.

No tengo código, he visto muchos ejemplos pero la mayoría llevan un botón yo lo necesito sin botón.

quisiera que me explicaran un ejemplo

Comment: Busca informacion sobre observers, yo utilizaria eso, en caso que no entiendas te explico

Comment: Podrías usar `TextWatcher` para hacer lo que necesitas, e hacer implementación de una interfaz para hacer el seteo de texto de un `fragment` a otro de forma mas sencilla.

Comment: Si me podrian esplicas con un ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Acá colocare 2 formas de hacer lo que necesitas, la primera de ellas como mencione en mi comentario, implementando una `interface` y con `TextWatcher`:

Crea una interfaz con un método parecido a `TextChangeListener` y declara un método `onTextChange(String text)`.

```
interface TextChangeListener{
    void onTextChange(String number);
}
```

Implementa la interfaz en el `Activity` contenedor.

```
class HostActivity extends Activity implements TextChangeListener{
   ...
   void onTextChange(String datos){
       secondFragment.updateNumber(datos)
   }
   ...
}
```

En `FirstFragment` (primer `fragment`), llama a la actividad utilizando la interfaz implementada en el listener `afterTextChanged()` de `TextWatcher`.

```
class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
    private TextChangeListener activity;

    @Override
    public onAttach(Context context){
         if(context instanceof TextChangeListener){
              activity = (TextChangeListener) context;
         }
    }

    dataEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override           
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            activity.onTextChange(s.toString);
        }
        ...
    );

...
}
```

En `SecondFragment` (Segundo `fragment`) al recibir la llamada de la actividad, actualiza el `EditText` o `TextView` con nuevos datos.

```
class SecondFragment extends Fragment{
    ...
    public void updateNumber(String datos){
        editText.setText(datos);
    }
}
```

Otra manera que puedes intentar es con [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Utiliza `EventBus` para publicar un evento de `FirstFragment`. El evento contendrá los datos que se completarán en `SecondFragment`. `SecondFragment` se suscribirá al evento y al recibir el evento, los datos se rellenarán en el `EditText`.